# How to send more email on framework laravel with cron job

Tags: php, laravel, email, cron

How to send more emails for example 1000 and more.
I use laravel framework and I want send emails on one request or cron job.

If use while and in it Mail fasade and send emails is slow. 
..but if use Mail fasade and in callback to more recipient then come email with more recipient.

How have I send emails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can push your mailes into a queue and schedule the `queue:work` command from your cron job.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#queueing-mail

1000 emails is a lot so it's normal that this takes time. Your mail server probably also throttles your emails so the server doesn't get flagged as a spam server.

Comment: thank your answer. If I muss use while for Mail fasade and then I will send emails for every separately?

Comment: Yeah, just queue all your emails in your while loop. Then the queue worker can send them all in the background without (really) slowing down your application.